# How to change width for container dynamically in iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am loading some HTML, Java script code into my iOS application. Its working fine, but, according to device height, I should have to change the animation size (width), I tried following code, but, I am very new to javascript calling into iOS.

my html page code of java script is

```
         var $ios9 = document.getElementById('container-ios9');
         var SW9 = new Wave9({
                                 width: 800,
                                 height: 40,
                                 container: $ios9,
                                 });
        </script>
```

and I am calling into native code as

```
if (self.view.frame.size.width <= 400) {
[_animationWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('container-ios9').width = 500"];
}
else {
    [_animationWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('container-ios9').width = 700"];
}
```

The above code is not changing the width, So,
Can anyone suggest me, how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: I think `document.getElementById('container-ios9').width` is wrong. It should be `document.getElementById('container-ios9').style.width`

Comment: you mean, this is right         [_animationWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('container-ios9').style.width = 400"];
 ?

Comment: Yes. Also, `document.getElement‌​ById('container-ios9‌​').style.width = '400px'` Did you tried?

Comment: yes tried, both are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of R & D, I fixed the issue by myself. I am posting this answer here, It will help someone future.

In HTML file, Java script code,

```
             if (window.screen.width <= 400) {
         var $ios9 = document.getElementById('container-ios9');
         var SW9 = new Wave9({
                                 width: 800,
                                 height: 40,
                                 container: $ios9,
                                 });
} else {
//other devices
        </script>
```